# GPS unit for road cycling and mountaineering

Tags: mountaineering, navigation, gps, biking

I am looking for a GPS device for road cycling (road navigation and gpx tracking) and mountaineering (topo maps, compass, barometric elevation / pressure). I am finding no products explicitly marketed for both, I am wondering if anyone has recommendations or hints?

So, more specifically, I would be looking for the following features:

- Navigation of a pre-programmed route on a bike, like in a car SatNav, ideally also showing speed / other stats in real-time as well
- Good topo map capability for the mountains
- Built-in barometer and digital compass
- Reasonable weather-proofing
- [optional] possibility to connect a heart-rate monitor
- [welcome] good battery life
- [budget] less is better, but no set figure - though if it is more than the cost of a hiking GPS and separate bike one, it seems preferable to buy two units?

Any suggestions? Garmin eTrex 30x seems to tick the boxes: https://buy.garmin.com/en-US/US/into-sports/handheld/etrex-30x/prod518048.html though I could not find any reviews about using it as a cycling computer.

Many thanks for any help